# Finding longest consecutive increase in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Date    Price
2021-01-01 29344.67
2021-01-02 32072.08
2021-01-03 33048.03
2021-01-04 32084.61
2021-01-05 34105.46
2021-01-06 36910.18
2021-01-07 39505.51
2021-01-08 40809.93
2021-01-09 40397.52
2021-01-10 38505.49

Date      object
Price    float64
dtype: object
```

And my goal is to find the longest consecutive period of growth.
It should return:
`Longest consecutive period was from 2021-01-04 to 2021-01-08 with increase of $8725.32`
and honestly I have no idea where to start with it. These are my first steps in pandas and I don't know which tools I should use to get this information.

Could anyone help me / point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detect your increasing sequence with cumsum on **decreasing**:

```
df['is_increasing'] = df['Price'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
```

You would get:

```
         Date     Price  is_increasing
0  2021-01-01  29344.67             0
1  2021-01-02  32072.08             0
2  2021-01-03  33048.03             0
3  2021-01-04  32084.61             1
4  2021-01-05  34105.46             1
5  2021-01-06  36910.18             1
6  2021-01-07  39505.51             1
7  2021-01-08  40809.93             1
8  2021-01-09  40397.52             2
9  2021-01-10  38505.49             3
```

Now, you can detect your longest sequence with

```
sizes=df.groupby('is_increasing')['Price'].transform('size')
df[sizes == sizes.max()]
```

And you get:

```
         Date     Price  is_increasing
3  2021-01-04  32084.61              1
4  2021-01-05  34105.46              1
5  2021-01-06  36910.18              1
6  2021-01-07  39505.51              1
7  2021-01-08  40809.93              1
```

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much! I tried working with diff() and cumsum() but couldn't puzzle it thogether. It works! You're amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Something like what Quang did for split the group , then pick the number of group

```
s = df.Price.diff().lt(0).cumsum()
out = df.loc[s==s.value_counts().sort_values().index[-1]]
Out[514]: 
         Date     Price
3  2021-01-04  32084.61
4  2021-01-05  34105.46
5  2021-01-06  36910.18
6  2021-01-07  39505.51
7  2021-01-08  40809.93
```